# C# DataReader error

Tags: c#, mysqldatareader

I looked for a solution to this problem on the forum, but I didn't find one for my problem. On button click, I receive error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first.

So, I tried to close all DataReaders after using them, I tried to use `CommandBehavior`, but none of them worked. I tried to use `using(MysqlCommand...)` but didn't work. What can I do? The strangest thing is that the code is working, but after each button press, I receive that error again. Any ideas?

Please don't flag question as a  duplicate, I know that the question exist here but the answer is missing for my problem I guess.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Drawing.Text;

namespace simulator
{
    public partial class Simulare : Form
    {
        public int corect = 0, incorect = 0;
        Timer timer;
        static string dataA = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM questions order by rand() limit 1";
        public int r1;
        public int r2;
        public int r3;
        public Simulare()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.FormClosing += Form1_FormClosing;
            label1.Text = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30).ToString("mm\\:ss");
            label10.Text = corect.ToString();
            label12.Text = incorect.ToString();
            //FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }
        private void simulare_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var startTime = DateTime.Now;
            timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };
            timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
            {
                TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) - (DateTime.Now - startTime);
                label1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss");
                if (ts.Minutes == 00 && ts.Seconds == 00)
                {
                    timer.Stop();
                    MessageBox.Show("Timpul a expirat. Ai picat!");
                    MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("select totalno from accounts where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection());
                        try
                        {
                            MySqlDataReader upad = upd.ExecuteReader();
                                while (upad.Read())
                                {
                                    int totalnu = (int)upad["totalno"];
                                    totalnu++;
                                    using (MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE accounts SET totalno=@totalnu where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection()))
                                    {
                                        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalnu", totalnu);
                                        int rows = update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                                upad.Close();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex2)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(ex2.Message);
                        }
                    }
            };
            timer.Start();
            select();
        }

        private void select()
        {
            using (ConnConfig.getConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(dataA, ConnConfig.getConnection());
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                MySqlDataReader rdra = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
                try
                {
                    while (rdra.Read())
                    {
                        label2.Text = rdra["question"].ToString();
                        label3.Text = rdra["answer1"].ToString();
                        label4.Text = rdra["answer2"].ToString();
                        label5.Text = rdra["answer3"].ToString();
                        r1 = (int)rdra["option1"];
                        r2 = (int)rdra["option2"];
                        r3 = (int)rdra["option3"];
                    }
                    rdra.Close();
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    ConnConfig.closeConn();
                }
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int result1 = checkBox1.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            int result2 = checkBox2.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            int result3 = checkBox3.CheckState == CheckState.Checked ? 1 : 0;
            using(ConnConfig.getConnection())
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(dataA, ConnConfig.getConnection());
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                try
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (checkBox1.Checked == false && checkBox2.Checked == false && checkBox3.Checked == false)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Bifati minim o casuta!");
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if ((result1 == r1) && (result2 == r2) && (result3 == r3))
                            {
                                corect++;
                                label10.Text = corect.ToString();
                                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                                checkBox2.Checked = false;
                                checkBox3.Checked = false;
                                select();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                incorect++;
                                label12.Text = incorect.ToString();
                                checkBox1.Checked = false;
                                checkBox2.Checked = false;
                                checkBox3.Checked = false;
                                select();
                            }
                            if (corect + incorect == 26)
                            {
                                int totalalll;
                                timer.Stop();
                                button1.Enabled = false;
                                MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("select * from accounts where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection());
                                MySqlDataReader upad = upd.ExecuteReader();
                                while (upad.Read())
                                {
                                    totalalll = (int)upad["totalall"];
                                    totalalll++;
                                    using (MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE accounts SET totalall=@totalalll where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection()))
                                    {
                                        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalalll", totalalll);
                                        Int32 rows = update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                                upad.Close();
                            }
                            if (corect == 26)
                            {
                                MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("select totalyes from accounts where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection());
                                MySqlDataReader upad = upd.ExecuteReader();
                                while (upad.Read())
                                {
                                    int totalda = (Int32)upad["totalyes"];
                                    totalda++;
                                    using (MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE accounts SET totalyes=@totalda where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection()))
                                    {
                                        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalda", totalda);
                                        int rows = update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                                upad.Close();
                                MessageBox.Show("Bravos");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("select totalno from accounts where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection());
                                MySqlDataReader upad = upd.ExecuteReader();
                                while (upad.Read())
                                {
                                    int totalnu = (int)upad["totalno"];
                                    totalnu++;
                                    using (MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE accounts SET totalno=@totalnu where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection()))
                                    {
                                        update.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totalnu", totalnu);
                                        int rows = update.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                    }
                                }
                                upad.Close();
                                MessageBox.Show("Mai invata!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    rdr.Close();
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    ConnConfig.closeConn();
                }
            }
        }

        private void Form1_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CloseReason == CloseReason.WindowsShutDown) return;

            if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                e.Cancel = false;
                timer.Stop();
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}

class ConnConfig
    {
        private static string conn = "string connection";
        public static MySqlConnection connect;

        private ConnConfig()
        {

        }
        public static MySqlConnection getConnection()
        {
            if(connect !=null){

                return connect;
            }
            else 
                try{
                    connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
                    connect.Open();
                    return connect;
                }
            catch(MySqlException e){
                throw new Exception("Cannot connect",e);
            }
        }
        public static void closeConn()
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
        public static void openConn()
        {
            connect.Open();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The guy who just '-1', if you're that smart, can you give me a solution?

Comment: What's the exact line where exception is thrown?

Comment: For the record it wasn't me who downvoted you :P.

Comment: After is checking if the answer is right or wrong, you can see that I called 'select()' function to select another question. And when is in the function, is jumping to these lines: 'TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) - (DateTime.Now - startTime);
                label1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss");
                if (ts.Minutes == 00 && ts.Seconds == 00)' and It keeps repeating them..I tried now with break point

Comment: @DiacuPaul have you set break points.. are you sure that the timer is not the issue..?

Comment: I know, don't get me wrong, but in my opinion if you disagree someone, you tell him why, right?..

Comment: The issue is at the timer MethodMan, how did you knew?

Comment: Probably because you used `ExecuteNonQuery` while reader was still open. Which isn't allowed.

Comment: Should I try to update that field as I did in the rest of the code?

Comment: Aaaa...actually, I used ExecuteNonQuery everywhere for update..

Comment: I see...well can you give me an example of how should I do? I don't really know how to work with timers..I need a countdown timer only with minutes and seconds..I have to modify that line where I used update,right?

Comment: ExecuteNonQuery is good for update, Inserts and Deletes but you are having a connection pooling issue it looks like.. why now create stored procedure to do you updates I think it will make debugging and maintaining much easier when doing Updates, Deletes, Inserts ..The Select query could also share the same stored procedure if you set it up properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the getConnection function

```
public static MySqlConnection getConnection()
    {
        MySqlConnection connect = null;
        try
        {
            connect = new MySqlConnection(connect);
            connect.Open();
            return connect;
        }
        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            throw new Exception("Cannot connect", e);
        }
    }
```

let all the other codes as it is

Comment: Now I get: `Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and the error appears when I try to open the form

Comment: `public static void closeConn()
        {
            connect.Close(); // -> this line
        }`

Comment: comment it    //connect.close();

Comment: Have you commented that closing line in the ConnConfig class?

Comment: Yes..I know...I did as you said above, if commented connect.Close(); and connect.Open() because there was an error too. Now I receive: `Specified cast is not valid.` :))

Comment: To line: `int totalnu = (int)upad["totalno"];`

Comment: change it as int totalnu = Convert.ToInt32(upad["totalno"]);

Comment: Awesome! It worked! Well, now I can remove openConn() and closeConn()? With those modifications in connaction class, the connection is open all the time?

Comment: You have to take care of closing connections. You should understand what i have done.. You wrote a code of opening one connection, and allowed it to close. But here i'm making you open several connections. Those must be closed properly

Comment: I will tell you the idea to close it.. Instead of using ConnConfig.getConnection(), use MySqlConnection conn1 = ConnConfig.getConnection() somewhere before and use conn1 and conn2. Then after all your use at the end of the method you can simply close by conn1.Close(); You understand?

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your exception is that you are executing other queries while you are still iterating over the results of an earlier query.
Bottom line you should not nest queries like you do if you use the same connection for the nested queries.

Answer (score 1):

You are using reader to fetch data from SQLCommand upd.

Then you are reading value.

After that you are using another SqlCommand 'update' to update the result..

Even when you use two different SQLCommands, you are using the same connection. Thats the problem. Use a sperate connection for the second SQLCommand and your problem will be solved.

Try this.

after the line

```
MessageBox.Show("Timpul a expirat. Ai picat!");
```

add like

```
MessageBox.Show("Timpul a expirat. Ai picat!");
MySqlConnection conn1 = ConnConfig.getConnection();
MySqlConnection conn2 = new MySqlConnection();
conn2.ConnectionString = conn1.ConnectionString;
conn2.Open();
```

and then in the line

```
MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("select totalno from accounts where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection());
```

change like

```
MySqlCommand upd = new MySqlCommand("select totalno from accounts where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", conn1);
```

and in line

```
using (MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE accounts SET totalno=@totalnu where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", ConnConfig.getConnection()))
```

change like

```
using (MySqlCommand update = new MySqlCommand("UPDATE accounts SET totalno=@totalnu where username = '" + Index.textBox1.Text + "'", conn2))
```

Comment: I understand, but in my situation. where should I close and re-open the connection? Because I have a MysqlCommand in another MysqlCommand

Comment: But I don't understand one thing..that if where are these lines, should be called only when timer is = 0..

Comment: Can you put the ConnConfig class?

Comment: I checked it with the problem before and after the solution i provided. And found it was the excact solution. The same error i got before applying the solution i provided and error gone after the solution. Now i'm gonna check with the timer. In the mean time will you please check Cleaning the solution, and also running it with release option other than debug..?

Comment: The error happens on the load event right? Or after you click any button?

Comment: It happens after I click button1. Is checking if the solution is right or wrong and then is trying to select another question with 'select()' but when is in function, is jumping to 'Load' function and it stucks at those 3 lines: 'TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30) - (DateTime.Now - startTime);
                label1.Text = ts.ToString("mm\\:ss");
                if (ts.Minutes == 00 && ts.Seconds == 00)'. Is not checking if the timer is 0

Comment: Error persists after Cleaning and rebuild